# VHDL Increment 10-bit Program Counter by 1

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make a 32-bit CPU using a modified MIPS instruction set in VHDL. I am currently trying to get my Program Counter to increment by 1 for the next instruction, unless it is a jump instruction which then the Program Counter will equal the Jump value.

```
entity PC is
Port ( PC_IN     : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0); --New PC in value (PC+1 or jump)
       PC_OUT    : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0); --PC out to instruction memory
       Jump_Inst : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0); --Jump address
       Jump      : in STD_LOGIC; --Jump MUX
       clk       : in STD_LOGIC);
end PC;

architecture Behavioral of PC is
begin

PC_IN <= (PC_IN + "0000000001") when (Jump = '0')
else Jump_Inst;     

process(clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then --If it is the next clock cycle (i.e time for the next instruction)
   PC_OUT <= PC_IN;

end if;
end process;     
end Behavioral;
```

I am getting errors at this line `PC_IN <= (PC_IN + "0000000001") when (Jump = '0')`. The errors consist of **cannot update 'in' object pc_in** and **0 definitions of operator "+" match here**, so it doesn't like me using the + operator and maybe pc_in needs to be an output?

Does anyone know how to get my program counter to increment by 1 for the next instruction? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Signal Jump is declared in another file where all the control signals are made. It then links to the PC file using component deceleration and port maps in a overhead file called cpu, which links my PC, Instruction Memory, Register, Control etc

Comment: So because I cant make an assignment to an object of mode in, should I change it to PC_Out instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PC_IN is defined as a `std_logic_vector`.  You don't show the libraries in use, but by default there are no defined operators for `+` for `std_logic_vector` in `std_logic_1164`.  Note your error message:

> 0 definitions of operator "+" match here

This is your hing that `+` isn't defined in this context.  In order to use the `+` operator, you need to include a library that has that support and use the appropriate type.

Your other error:

> cannot update 'in' object pc_in

Tells you that you cannot set an `in` port.  Notably, `PC_IN` is an input, yet you are trying to drive `PC_IN`.  Perhaps you mean to drive `PC_OUT`?

I won't mention the alternate method, but you should probably use `numeric_std` in this case.  For example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

...

PC_OUT <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PC_IN) + 1) when (Jump = '0') else Jump_Inst;
```

Comment: Thank you that seemed to solve the problem. I am still getting the error about updating an in object, but you have got the value to increment. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @oodan123 Your error related to `cannot update 'in' object pc_in` is because `PC_IN` is an input, and you are assigning it.  You should probably be assigning `PC_OUT`.  I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: For non-2008 revision compliant VHDL tools (without sequential conditional signal assignment where the signal assignment occurs in a process):
   `if Jump = '0' then
       PC_OUT <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(PC_IN) + 1);
    else
        PC_OUT <= Jump_Inst;
    end if;`  In -2008 there's also package numeric_std_unsigned that treats std_logic_vector as unsigned and provides a "+" without the type conversions.

Comment: @user1155120 The problem with `numeric_std_unsigned` is the same as the older, proprietary `std_logic_unsigned` and `std_logic_arith`.  They treat all `std_logic_vectors` as unsigned.  This can be problematic, especially if you want signed values as well.  I also think the use of `unsigned` and `signed` is much more explicit, and the intent is much more clear.  Which is why I steered away from the "alternate method."